# when switch between tabs orientation make bug and app comes to landscape then to portrait react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

im developing react native app and want to lock to portrait when i switch between tabs orientation becomes landscape and then portrait and after this application buged and orientation not working till do this again switch between tabs

### what try

i try using library like react-native-orientation-locker and issue not solved

react native version 63.3
react 16.13.11

changed androidmanifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and change app.json

```
  "orientation": "portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-native-orientation-locker just add to App.js

```
    useEffect(() => {
     Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    }, []);
```

If you properly added react-native-orientation-locker it should work.

Comment: You have to import Orientation from react-native-orientation-locker.

Comment: i try this but nothing happend